# get commit id from commit message git

Tags: git, github

I had resolved a bug one month before, but still seems to be there are some issues with it.
But I don't even remember what changes I had done so far to fix that. I had noted the bug name
that time. So to find its commit Id there is only one way that go through the `git log` and search in `commit` messages. 
I tried this way :

```
      git log  --author=githubUser | grep "65243"
```

But its just returning me the message like :

```
     merge UI Developers Work #65243
```

Is there any way to get its commit id by doing `grep` in to it.

The message in the git log would be in the following format:

```
    commit <commit_id>
    Author: githubUser <githubUser@companyname.com>
    Date:   Thu Jul X 15:55:23 2014 +0530

        Bug fixed #65243
```

Comment: Take a look at toreks answer. He also mentions the `--grep` option which allows you to search for a string in the commit message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two methods to do what you want, depending on exactly what you want.

The first and shortest is to use [gitrevisions](http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) syntax to specify the "first" revision that contains a given string in its commit message:

```
git rev-parse :/65243
```

and:

```
git show :/65243
```

Quoting from the documentation linked above:

> A colon, followed by a slash, followed by a text, names a commit whose commit message matches the specified regular expression. This name returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from any ref. If the commit message starts with a ! you have to repeat that; the special sequence :/!, followed by something else than !, is reserved for now. The regular expression can match any part of the commit message. To match messages starting with a string, one can use e.g. :/^foo.

This form of expression names a specific commit (i.e., it has the same usage as a raw SHA-1 ID), which is why `git rev-parse` will show you the revision-ID and `git show` will show you the commit itself.

---

If that picks the wrong revision, use `git log --grep=65243` to limit its output to those commits that contain the specified regular expression in their commit messages.  The difference is that this looks only at the same revisions that `git log` would show otherwise (so you may add additional limiters), and shows all matching revisions.  That is, you can do things like:

```
git log --since=... --before=... --author=... --grep=65243 branch~30..branch
```

to see commits that are reachable from `branch` but not from `branch~30`, happened between the two time stamps, have the given author, and contain `65243`.  (Add `--oneline` or a `--format=pretty:...` string to the `git log` command if desired, etc.)

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be exact answer

Answer (score 3):

Run git log to get all the commit ids you want by date range, so if you are aware of the month of your changes, you can probably narrow down your search :)

```
git log --before={2014-02-01} --after={2014-01-01} --author="your name"
```

ie. in the above example, I'm grabbing all the changes made in the month of January 2014

Comment: :- I don't have even single letter of commit id

Comment: Do you know the date range of the commit?

Comment: It would be 16 Jul 2014, let me try this