# How to use brace expansion in gitrevisions <text>

Tags: git, bash

Using GNU Bash 4.3 and Git 2.1.4, I encountered difficulty using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) with [gitrevisions syntax](https://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions).

Specifically, I want to [get the Git commit IDs for some specific commit messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236402). Here is the log:

```
$ git log --format=oneline 
924d9120dec9f61d0f99a5155c51bad63d24b37f Commit 10
c62b2f68ea6b8ff047dd5f1e99010ebf434709ef Commit 9
feec2d76977521018ff33fd6e109530fdb69291d Commit 8
9a25b2ea11d0aa19af33761c7c81bd10d0f17949 Commit 7
c7b02e556738e7cd2a2459e07af731e5677ab090 Commit 6
1bf5b98cf90340e714bd0bd13c7721f94749fa5f Commit 5
8a9c25eda46b3424a870584e4a8a4f90f6e5aa2c Commit 4
0ecf2464ec82a3aa74abb6f6c2127315ef4c2495 Commit 3
e18bdb2ae52f2149421965ff69d96dba46cd7c0a Commit 2
cf10d47067bef60ae787e5421e32b4541bdf52be Commit 1
```

I want to return the commit IDs of commits 5 and 10. As a workaround, I can do this using shell variables in a `for` loop:

```
$ for i in {5,10}; do git rev-parse :/"Commit $i"; done
1bf5b98cf90340e714bd0bd13c7721f94749fa5f
924d9120dec9f61d0f99a5155c51bad63d24b37f
```

But I would prefer a more concise solution. Unfortunately, brace expansion does not seem to work here, even with various escape sequences attempted:

```
$ git rev-parse :/"Commit {5,10}" # No escaping used
:/Commit {5,10}
fatal: ambiguous argument ':/Commit {5,10}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git rev-parse :/"Commit \{5,10\}" # Attempt to pass braces to shell for expansion
:/Commit \{5,10\}
fatal: ambiguous argument ':/Commit \{5,10\}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: `for i in {5,10}` and `for i in 5 10` are exactly the same, except brace expansion requires you to type two extra characters. BE would only be useful here if you had a contiguous range of commits.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to *append* the braced part to the gitrevisions `<text>`:

```
$ git rev-parse :/'Commit '{5,10}
1bf5b98cf90340e714bd0bd13c7721f94749fa5f
924d9120dec9f61d0f99a5155c51bad63d24b37f
```